# How can I stop anchors link from another page scrolling to correct section then jumping to top?

Tags: html, scroll, hyperlink, anchor, smooth-scrolling

On my WordPress website I have a main navigation containing anchor links that scroll to different sections of the home page (e.g)

```
<a href="http://thisismysite.com#about">About Us</a>
```

However when the main navigation links are clicked from sub pages (e.g. if the navigation links are clicked from a page like the below)

http://thisismysite.com/contact-us

it successfully goes back to the home page and scrolls to the correct anchor, but  it then jumps to the top of the page when the page loads completely.

Any ideas what can fix this?

Comment: show us your scrolling code

Comment: it's just a basic anchor. here is the anchor

<h3 id="about">About Us</h3>

here is the link (from the main navigation)

<a href="http://keyskillsnortheast.com/#about">About Us</a>